# Can I replace CSS borders with ASCII style borders?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to replace the standard CSS borders with ASCII symbols like "-" and "+" without using JavaScript?

I want to draw borders around boxes and use ASCII symbols to style my website. The borders should look like:

```
+-----------+
|           |
+-----------+
```

The only solution I found until now is to "hardcode" the borders inside the HTML but I want it more dynamic. I don't want to use JavaScript.

Comment: Try: [border: dashed black;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border)

Comment: yes i know "border: dashed" but with that i don't have the plus (+) sign at the corners and it's an ugly wannabe ASCII :)

Comment: Border-image can do that

Comment: already play around with "border-image" but it stretch the image when i have boxes with different widths and looks not that good.

Answer (score 1):

Use `after` & `before` CSS

```css
.box {
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px dashed red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.box::after {
    content: "+";
    position: absolute;
    left: -6px;
    top: -13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: red;
}

.box::before {
    content: "+";
    position: absolute;
    right: -6px;
    top: -13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: red;
}

.box .inner::after {
    content: "+";
    position: absolute;
    left: -6px;
    bottom: -11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: red;
}

.box .inner::before {
    content: "+";
    position: absolute;
    right: -6px;
    bottom: -11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="inner">
    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes i also think about the ::after and ::before option but it is not the nicest looking way. but thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of stroke-dasharray rectangle and text located at the corners:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="421" height="220" viewBox="0 0 420 220">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .edge {
        fill: white;
        stroke: green;
        stroke-dasharray: 5;
        stroke-width: 1.0px;
      }
  .corner_background {
    fill: white;
      }
      .corner {
        fill: green;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;        
      }

    </style>
  </defs>
 
  <g>
    <rect class="edge" x="10" y="10" width="400" height="200"/>
    <rect class="corner_background" x="0" y="0" width="16" height="16"/>
    <text class="corner" x="6" y="14">+</text>
    <rect class="corner_background" x="400" y="0" width="16" height="16"/>
    <text class="corner" x="406" y="14">+</text>
    <rect class="corner_background" x="0" y="200" width="16" height="16"/>
    <text class="corner" x="6" y="214">+</text>
    <rect class="corner_background" x="400" y="200" width="16" height="16"/>
    <text class="corner" x="406" y="214">+</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```